# Pihole deployment restarting with helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install pihole on a Kubernetes cluster on Docker via helm. I'm following [this guide](https://kauri.io/68-selfhost-pihole-on-kubernetes-and-block-ads-and/5268e3daace249aba7db0597b47591ef/a) to do so. Everything seems to go smoothly. I get a completion:

```
NAME: pihole
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Sep 30 22:22:15 2020
NAMESPACE: pihole
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
```

But the pihole never reaches the ready state, it just restarts after a couple minutes. Upon inspecting the pod I see:

```
lastState:
    terminated:
        containerID: docker://16e2a318b460d4d5aebd502175fb688fc150993940181827a506c086e2cb326a
        exitCode: 0
        finishedAt: "2020-09-30T22:01:55Z"
        reason: Completed
        startedAt: "2020-09-30T21:59:17Z"
```

How do I prevent this from continually restarting once it's complete?

Here is the output of kubectl logs <POD_NAME>:

```
[s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
[fix-attrs.d] 01-resolver-resolv: applying...
[fix-attrs.d] 01-resolver-resolv: exited 0.
[fix-attrs.d] done.
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
[cont-init.d] 20-start.sh: executing...
 ::: Starting docker specific checks & setup for docker pihole/pihole
  [✓] Update local cache of available packages
  [i] Existing PHP installation detected : PHP version 7.0.33-0+deb9u8

  [i] Installing configs from /etc/.pihole...
  [i] Existing dnsmasq.conf found... it is not a Pi-hole file, leaving alone!
  [✓] Copying 01-pihole.conf to /etc/dnsmasq.d/01-pihole.conf
chown: cannot access '': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access '/etc/pihole/dhcp.leases': No such file or directory
::: Pre existing WEBPASSWORD found
Using default DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4
DNSMasq binding to default interface: eth0
Added ENV to php:
                        "PHP_ERROR_LOG" => "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log",
                        "ServerIP" => "0.0.0.0",
                        "VIRTUAL_HOST" => "pi.hole",
Using IPv4 and IPv6
::: Preexisting ad list /etc/pihole/adlists.list detected ((exiting setup_blocklists early))
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts
https://mirror1.malwaredomains.com/files/justdomains
::: Testing pihole-FTL DNS: FTL started!
::: Testing lighttpd config: Syntax OK
::: All config checks passed, cleared for startup ...
 ::: Docker start setup complete
  [✗] DNS resolution is currently unavailable
```

Comment: Can you show the logs of the pod kubectl logs <POD_NAME>

Comment: @Zambozo I've added the logs for that pod

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone with this issue.

Resolution is here - [chown: cannot access '/etc/pihole/dhcp.leases': No such file or directory](https://github.com/MoJo2600/pihole-kubernetes/issues/69)

> This happens for me as well. I used that same tutorial to set up my
> cluster. If you are using a persistent volume as well, use a ssh
> connection to get to your drive and run these two commands.

```
ls -l ----> this will show the owner and user of each file they all should be www-data if not run this cmd
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data pihole from the /mnt/ssd directory described in the tutorial. This will allow you to add more whitelists/blacklists/adlists from the web portal.
```